# Can I transfer my online character from the PC to PS3?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online, psn

I own GTA V for both PS3 and PC. I want to transfer my online character from the PC version to the PS3.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

No.  According to the [Rockstar Support Article](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/202892778-Transferring-Your-Previous-Grand-Theft-Auto-Online-Characters-and-Progression-to-PlayStation-4-Xbox-One-or-PC) you can only transfer to:

- PS4 (from PS3 or Xbox 360)
- Xbox One (from PS3 or Xbox 360)
- PC (from PS3, PS4, Xbox 360 or Xbox One)